# Usage of a handler

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, runnable, android-handler

I'm recently getting involved in some concurrent programming specially with Java and Android.

I have some questions regarding Handlers. 
1 - It is known that we need to associate a Handler with a thread, and it will run on the thread it was invoked on. However, in some examples on SO, the user is doing

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
 handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}


    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //Do whatever
        handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
    }
};
```

In this example, I assume we are doing the Handler thing on the UI Thread, RIGHT ?

Can I do a network operation here in place of `//DO Whatever` ? I don't think so, because we are on the main thread.

Is doing this pointless ? As one may use AsyncTask to replace this task ?

How can I apply this same example but not on the UI thread, rather a seperate thread ?

Do thread or Runnables have something similar to post delayed ?

Is it common to use the handler just for its postdelayed feature and not the main task handlers are made for, ie, being the middle man between the thread and the UI/Activity ?

Comment: Generally handllers are usefull when you want to access UI components form worker/background thread or AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Handlers are useful only when you want update UI. As you may know we cannot update UI from non UI Thread. If you are going to do some network stuff in background thread, and then update UI, you have to use Handler class or AsyncTask or you can do like this:

(from non UI Thread)

```
SomeView.post(new Runnable() {
   //updating UI
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If whatever you are doing is "heavy" you should be doing it in a Thread. If you do not explicitly start it in its own thread, then it will run on the main (UI) thread which may be noticeable as jittery or slow to respond interface by your users.

Interestingly when you are using a thread it is often useful to also use a Handler as a means of communication between the work thread that you are starting and the main thread.

A typical Thread/Handler interaction might look something like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler(){
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg){
    if(msg.what == 0){
        updateUI();
    }else{
        showErrorDialog();
    }
}};

Thread t = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run(){
    doSomeWork();
    if(succeed){
        //we can't update the UI from here so we'll signal our handler and it will do it for us.
        h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }else{
        h.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
}   };
```

In general though, the take home is that you should use a Thread any time you are doing some work that could be long running or very intensive (i.e. anything network, file IO, heavy arithmatic, etc).